# I was in a technical interview and asked to make a structure like this..

Tags: c, malloc, structure

Make a structure and give it three members like this,

```
 struct student{
                 int rollno;
                 char name[10];
                 int arr[];
                }stud1, stud2;
```

now give 4 records of marks to stud1, and 5 records of marks to stud2.
I told the interviewer that we have to give array some size otherwise it is not going to be assigned any space , or it would give compiler error.
He said according to new standards of C , it is possible.
Finally i couldn't understand how to do it.Do anyone have suggestions ?
I tried to do a realloc but i was not sure myself if it would work.

Comment: I like the sharing. The question makes sense and is well connected to your experience. This kind of question will surely be appreciated by job-seekers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sample itself is wrong because automatic objects (stud1 and stud2) can not be declared. But you can write

```
struct student *s = malloc(sizeof *s + number_of_arr_elems * sizeof s->arr[0]);
```

Comment: But what was the need to give space like this, i mean a pointer inside the structure can also serve the purpose too..

Comment: You will have to manage a second dynamic memory area then.  E.g. now, you are done with 'free(s)'; a pointer needs an extra 'free(s->arr)'. Performance might be another reason because you need to allocate now two instead one object on heap.

Answer (score 3):

It's a *flexible array member*. This feature has been added in C99. It allows the last member of a structure type to have an incomplete array type. This feature is explained in 6.7.2.1 in C99 Standard.

> "As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. [...]"

The rest of the paragraph describes its usage.